# how to load a json from parent directory

Tags: python

I have to load a configuration file from parent directory. Here is the folder structure :

```
.
├── cleanup
├── _conf.json
├── data
│   ├── all_combine_200k.csv
│   ├── cyclegear.csv
│   ├── make_dataset.py
│   └── R_Result_Temp.csv
├── features
│   ├── add_template_python.py
│   ├── build_features.py
│   ├── create_templates.py
│   ├── read_template_python.py
│   └── template_features_req.proto
├── __init__.py
├── models
│   ├── hmm
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── predict_model.py
│   └── train_model.py
├── remotedb
│   └── cyclegeardb.py
├── utils
│   ├── c_print.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── visualization
    ├── __init__.py
    └── visualize.py
```

I am in `add_template_python.py` and need to load `_conf.json` from the `src` directory.

In order to import stuff from other directories I just use `sys.path.append('..')` but that won't work here. What code can load json file from parent directory?

Comment: Load `"../_conf.json"`.

Comment: @DYZ You're missing if `add_template_python` isn't executed in CWD.

Comment: @erip "_conf.json" is not in "cleanup", it is in the root of the project.

Comment: Please respond to us instead of editing your post. It makes it very confusing for answers.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The last solution worked out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnM. If it solved your problem, you can select it as the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: I will, it just says to wait a minute :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the path to the the file with:

```
path_to_json = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..', '_conf.py')
```

This will not normalize the path. If that's important, you can normalize it with `os.path.normpath`.

Answer (score 0):

**Normalized Path:**

```
file_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..', '_conf.json'))
```